# ItemLookup using Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

How can I look up one specific item. I'm not trying to lookup the product using the ASIN, I want to the exact product using the `OfferListingId`

The API keeps returning the error:

```
 [Message] => 9FKKDHB9XOBXVQWPMCJQF%2F6AF69WZCTZ76LD6TX2JWIW1QHSOW0XZWOSZ3HX%2B1GVPWXW%2FNKWAQWHRIZKG34SW3AXSZMUDGA%2FMT0WLVCKXJDORBPI0%2FMDSW%3D%3D is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry your request.
```

This is the ID returned by a search I performed via the API.

I have the IDType set like this:

```
"IdType" => "ASIN",
```

The docs state:

> Default: ASIN
>
> Valid Values: SKU | UPC | EAN | ISBN

So, am I to believe that I can't do an `itemLookup` using their own internally assigned `OfferListingId`?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot look for an item based on an OfferListingId. The OfferListingId is a unique id akin to a price tag. For instance, if you sell three of the same shirt, you will have three different OfferListingId (see [Checking for an Offer Listing ID](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CheckingforanOfferListingID.html)).

Amazon does not offer the ability to search by OfferListingId. Your best bet is to use the itemLookup operation with the Offers response, then iterate through the OfferListings until you find the OfferListingId you are interested in.